# Is there a way in Meteor to immediately re-render?

Tags: meteor

I currently have a button that when pushed, opens up a text box. I want to do it so that the focus is automatically on this text box when the button is pushed.

I have the following HTML to render the button and input, and toggle between the button/input

```
    {{#if modeIs 'edit' }}
    <input class="col-xs-9" placeholder="Enter your new task and press enter"  id="insertTask" type="text"/>
    {{else}}
    <button id="btnNewTask"  class="btn btn-success btn-lg" role="button">New Task</button>
    {{/if}}
```

Helper function to check the mode.

```
Template.insertNewTask.helpers({
    modeIs: function (modeToCheck) {
        return Session.equals('mode', modeToCheck);

    }
});
```

This is the code I would like to use when the button is clicked to change the mode and focus on the input.

```
'click #btnNewTask': function (event, template) {
    Session.set('mode', 'edit');
    var input = $(template.find('#insertTask'));

    if(input){
        input.focus();
    }

},
```

The bit to change the 'mode' works and the button changes to a text box when I click on it.

My problem is this query $(template.find('#insertTask')); returns nothing because although I've set the mode, it hasn't re-rendered the HTML yet and the text box doesn't actually exist yet.

Is there a way that when I set the mode to 'edit', to tell Meteor to just immediately re-render the HTML before proceeding with the rest of the function? Is there a better way to structure my code so that I can reference HTML components that don't exist until after Meteor re-renders the HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`rendered`](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered) hook:

```
Template.insertNewTask.rendered = function() {
  var $input = $("#insertTask");
  if (Session.equals('mode', 'edit')) $input.focus()
}
```

You could set another flag somewhere to indicate when you want to focus the input (eg. if you don't always want to focus it after rendering the edit view, just after clicking the button).